# Homebrew won't link git

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew, git

I am trying to enable autocomplete for git on my mac (currently running El Capitan) but I am having troubles with Homebrew.

So far, I have installed **bash-completion** and added the lines in my **bash_profile**, as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970728/homebrews-git-not-using-completion) The problem comes when doing brew install git (although there must be another git installed in my machine sin I have used it).

After reinstalling brew, I get that git is installed but it's not link:

```
Warning: git-2.7.3 already installed, it's just not linked
```

I try using the command brew link git and I get this:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.7.3... 
Error: Could not symlink share/git-core/contrib
/usr/local/share/git-core is not writable.
```

Have anybody faced this situation before? How can I link git and what's exactly the "linking" problem?

Comment: Please post the output of:  ls -Old /usr/local   The problem might be that SIP (System Integrity Protection) made /usr/local read only...

Comment: also check with "brew doctor" if it reports any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **brew doctor** to see what's was happening..  It seems like there were some broken links.

The solution: I unlinked them, then I was able to run **brew link git** successfully. And now auto-completion works fine